# ¿Por qué al realizar un commit de una transacción con SQLite me dice que la base de datos está bloqueada?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, sqlite

Mi problema es el siguiente: al momento de realizar operaciones con la base de datos SQLite, no tengo ningún tipo de inconveniente. Sin embargo, al intentar realizar la siguiente transacción, en la linea:

```
tr.Commit()
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: database is locked

database is locked
```

El código completo del método es el que sigue a continuación:

```
Public Sub DefinirMonedaPorDefecto(ByVal idMoneda As Integer)
    Using cnx As New SQLiteConnection(connstring)
        cnx.Open()

        Using tr As SQLiteTransaction = cnx.BeginTransaction()
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(cnx)
                cmd.Transaction = tr

                Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE Monedas SET favorito = False WHERE favorito = True"
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                sqlQuery = "UPDATE Monedas SET favorito = True WHERE id = @id"
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idMoneda)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using

            tr.Commit()
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Muchas gracias!